# Cannot run Traefik in a Docker container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, traefik

I'm trying to Dockerise my server and Traefik seems to be the best way to manage the web traffic and direct it to the appropriate containers. I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-docker-traefik-proxy/#step-install-and-configure-traefik-reverse-proxy), but when I enter the web address into my browser, nothing happens. It basically configures a Traefik container using Docker Compose.

The domain name referenced in the traefik.toml file and the docker-compose.yml file is stored on the dynamic DNS service dynu.com, where an A record pointing to the IP of the current server is registered. However, I haven't got either Apache or Nginx running on my server. I've looked at a few tutorials for Traefik, and they aren't clear as to whether you need Apache/Nginx installed on your server and the domain name configured on whichever of the two you're using *before* starting the tutorial. I thought Traefik was a replacement for Nginx, but do you need Nginx running as well?

My aim is to have several sites/apps running on the same server, each with separate domain names. I've got a host for the server, which is what I've configured in the Traefik file, but I'd like to use different domain names for different apps/sites.

Comment: Traefik is a reverse proxy, it's not a replacement for ngnix.  You still need something that creates a website,..  It could be ngnix with some static files, but often it's maybe a PHP / Nodes / Java / Go / Rust etc that your reverse proxying too.

Answer (score 0):

Traefik is a reverse proxy and load balancer.

NGINX is a web server which can also be used as a reverse proxy, load balancer, mail proxy and HTTP cache.

A reverse proxy is just an intermediary server that forwards requests to other servers/applications. So you will still need to have your sites/apps running and available through a webserver in order to do any reverse proxying.

The selling points of traefik are that it automates SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt
and provides a simple way of proxying applications within a docker-compose config.

NGINX can also do reverse proxying, but is a bit more evolved. You have to edit static configs and reload the process. As long as you can get your application/webiste hosted on an internal port with an http server (node.js, etc) you can reverse proxy it with either traefik or NGINX.

If you setup traefik according to the guide, you should be able to access the dashboard at http://localhost:8080/

[Reverse proxy definition from NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/)

And the [traefik community forums](https://community.containo.us/c/traefik/traefik-v2/10) is a good place to start.